# How to concatenate ID of table data (td) field with server side value?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to concatenate the table data `<td>` ID with the server side value.
The dot operator does not work.

HTML code.

```
<td id="no_".<%=item.Id%>>
```

JavaScript code, where I want to use its value

```
var tblcd=$("#tc_".id).val();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like below

```
<td id="no_<%=item.Id%>">
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this, Simply

```
<td id="no_<%=item.Id%>" >
```

**"."**  wont work like you are trying

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td id="no_<%=item.Id%>">
```

And to get a value:

```
$('#mytable tr').each(function() {
var tblcd = $(this).find("td").attr("id").split("_")[1];    
});
```